# Best practice to implement count based subscription model?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Currently I have implemented a system where user subscribes to a plan for specific number of events. Whenever a new event is being created I am checking count against that user, say

```
SELECT COUNT(*|id) FROM events WHERE end_date < $date && userId = $id
```

This was working fine when number of events were small. But now table has more than 6 million rows and say one user has more than million events. This is causing performance slow down and high CPU.

What could be the best approach to make it more performant and scalable?

DB used is MySQL and backend is in .NET6. Index are present on all needed columns.

Comment: Have you considered Partitioning the table based on the end_date?

Comment: Please post TEST results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE events;  B) SHOW INDEX FROM events; SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "events"; for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Summarize the data each, say, day.  Then most or all of the `COUNT` becomes a faster`SUM` of subtotals:  [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Plan B:  `UPDATE counters SET ct = ct + 1 WHERE userId = $id`  (This won't work if `$date` is not effectively `NOW()`.)